# SoundCloud API, like a track (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, soundcloud

While making a SoundCloud desktop client in VB.net I ran into trouble: I simply cannot like and unlike tracks.

Logging in, playing music, Getting likes, ... all perfectly working, but liking tracks gives me a 404 (File not found) error.

This is the code I'm using:

```
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites" & "?client_id=" & Soundcloud.client_ID & "&oauth_token=" & _Token)
request.Method = "PUT"
Dim postData As String = Track.id
Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
dataStream.Close()
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Console.WriteLine(CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusDescription)
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)
reader.Close()
dataStream.Close()
response.Close()
```

The developers site doesn't really tell much, it only says this:
"GET, PUT, DELETE   /users/{id}/favorites/{id}  track favorited by the user"

Anyone able to help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think, looking at the documentation your url should be like `https://api.soundcloud.com/users/USERID/favorites/TRACKID.json?...`. I assume doing a `PUT` to this url should like the track ID in the url (it doesn't mention sending the ID in the request body), and then doing a `DELETE` to the same url would unlike it. I've never used this API, that's just my take on the documentation.

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, you can use everything from /users/<id> for /me/. Having the track ID in the URL also gives a 404.

Comment: Ah, god, I'm stupid.
I replaced the URL with "https://api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites/" & Track.id & "?client_id=" & Soundcloud.client_ID & "&oauth_token=" & _Token
That didn't work, but it did once I set the PostData to String.Empty...

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced the URL with "api.soundcloud.com/me/favorites/"; & Track.id & "?client_id=" & Soundcloud.client_ID & "&oauth_token=" & _Token

That didn't work, but it did once I set the PostData to String.Empty... Thanks anyways!